# Interface compile options for imported library in older CMake versions

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create an imported target in CMake and specify a compiler option to use with my target from any downstream project. It looks similar to the snippet below (`-O3` is just an example, the use case is a bit more sophisticated):

```
add_library(Foo::Foo UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Foo::Foo
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-O3")
```

The issue is that this isn't supported by CMake versions older than 2.8.12.

Is there a way to implement this mechanism in the older versions or are there any reasonable alternatives?

Comment: "Is there a way to implement this mechanism in the older versions?" - Do you want to implement a thing which behaves like IMPORTED target but without CMake support for it? - No, you cannot implement such thing. This is why old `FindXXX.cmake` scripts set variables like `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `XXX_LIBRARIES` and so on. In your `FindXXX.cmake` script you may set some variable - say, `FOO_COMPILE_OPTIONS` - to `-O3`, so a user of your library will use `add_compile_options(${FOO_COMPILE_OPTIONS})`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Let me be a bit more clear, I'm trying to make this working in 2.8.11 which supports imported targets and for example `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` works as expected with 2.8.11. However I could not figure out how to associate compiler options with an imported target. `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` seems to appear only in 2.8.12. I agree that `FOO_COMPILE_OPTIONS` approach would work in this case but I was trying to minimize extra actions on user side.

Comment: Got it. (BTW, your comment should be a part of the question, as it describes the problem.) Looking into [CMake 2.8.11 documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html), I actually see no `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` property. But there is no `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property too. There is even no `add_compile_options` command. It seems, that CMake 2.8.11 doesn't know "compile options" at all. Have you tried to use `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property for your purpose? Probably, this is the exact property intended for compile options in older CMake.